# regexp in MATLAB does not read parenthesis to match

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to match two strings using regexp but the function returns the value only if there are no parenthesis in the strings.

eg:

```
regexp('Amidation(N)','Amidation(N)')
returns

0
```

but

```
regexp('Amidation ()','Amidation()')
returns
1
```

Also it matches for:

```
regexp('Amidation-','Amidation-')
returns 1
```

I tried using strcmp, but that does not read multiple arguments in a string.

eg:

```
strcmp('Amidation;Acetylation (E);Phosphorylation','Acetylation (E)')
returns 0
```

but

```
strcmp('Amidation (E)','Amidation (E)')
returns 1.
```

I need a function like:

```
match_function('Amidation (E)','Amidation (G)')
returns 0
```

and

```
match_function('Amidation (E)','Amidation (E)')
returns 1
```

Please let me know which function I should be using

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the parentheses with a backslash (`\`) if you want to match parentheses as they are [a regex symbol for performing grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
regexp('Amidation(N)','Amidation\(N\)')
```

If you want to match literal strings with `regexp`, consider using [`regexptranslate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexptranslate.html) which can escape all special characters for you.

```
escaped_pattern = regexptranslate('escape', 'Amidation(N)');
regexp('Amidation(N)', escaped_pattern)
```

Comment: Good idea to use `regexptranslate` for the escaping!